# Is it possible to be connected to two different bluetooth devices at the same time?

Tags: bluetooth, a2dp

I'd like to be able to send A2DP to my car stereo while at the same time sending phone calls to the speakerphone I have in my car.  I haven't bought the stereo adapter yet, since I wanted to find out if this setup would work, otherwise I would just try it. ;)

Thanks!

Comment: Are your car's stereo and speakerphone two different devices? In my car it's only one device using mutliple different bluetooth profiles at the same time. Of course, that works as expected.

Comment: Yes, I have a bluetooth speakerphone already, but I was thinking about buying a bluetooth adapter that could be connected to the aux in of my stereo for A2DP.

Comment: Ah ok. I would expect it to work but I didn't test it. And expectations are no answers ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Answer:

Yes, you can have multiple bluetooth devices connected to your phone.

## App to manage your bluetooth devices

Additionally, you can use [Smart Bluetooth Widget Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mdrtools.smartbluetoothwidget) by MDR Tools, Inc. available from Google Play Store to help you manage those devices:

> This is a must have widget for your android if you have any bluetooth devices.
>
> It adds a bluetooth icon to your home screen, and by just clicking on it, It will display you the list of paired devices and you can just click and connect to your bluetooth devices. No need to go to settings screen, turn the bluetooth on, and connect to your devices.
>
> When you walk away from your bluetooth device, this widget not just cancels the bluetooth connection, It also turns off the bluetooth to save more from the battery.
>
> You can also connect to multiple bluetooth devices at the same time.
> You can connect to your speaker, and your headset at the same time.

There's also a free version [Smart Bluetooth Widget Free](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mdrtools.smartbluetoothwidget.free).

[image: Smart Bluetooth Widget - Turning bluetooth on] [image: Smart Bluetooth Widget - List of paired devices]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

However the limitation I found is that, output can only go to one bluetooth device connected, and not to all the bluetooth devices simultaneously.

For instance, [Throw is a feature](http://developer.sonymobile.com/2013/01/08/play-your-mobile-content-on-any-device-with-the-new-throw-feature/) that came with Sony Xperia Z2, which manages connections to multiple Bluetooth devices and commands and gives options which connected device you might wanna send your output to.

Thus, you could have a bluetooth speaker, bluetooth headset and a bluetooth earbuds all connected to your phone, but you select which to 'Throw' the sound to at any point in time, and can switch in between seamlessly easily instantly.

My personal experience with Throw was nice.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can be connected to two or more bluetooth devices at the same time.  On android, you can specify that your car be used for call audio, while your stereo be used for media audio.  You accomplish this by going to the android device settings and adjusting the profiles used for each device.