# How to pair Apple Wireless keyboard with Android 2.3.5 -phone and iPad?

Tags: bluetooth, keyboard, bluetooth-pairing

I use the Apple Wireless -keyboard. I want to be able to write with only one keyboard: control with it things such as iPad and my Android -phone. I tried BlueKeyboard JP [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Aj9qC3oKcZU) but I was unable to get it working. It was very easy to get the keyboard synced with iPad but haven't been able to get it working with any of my Android -devices. How can I pair many devices to one BT -keyboard? Is there some easy way to switch between them? Is there some easy way to control many devices with one BT -keyboard?

**Perhaps related**

1. [Is it possible to be connected to two different bluetooth devices at the same time?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/16087/is-it-possible-to-be-connected-to-two-different-bluetooth-devices-at-the-same-ti)

Comment: Apple bluetooth and Android bluetooth are extremely dodgy to work with, let alone pair with... best bet is to get a ordinary bluetooth keyboard that is not tied to apple... :)

Comment: ...it is very unstable for me, it should still work like [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8zj573pUKYc).

Comment: What is your android device? Just because one worked with google nexus s and apple keyboard as per in the youtubey, does not mean its guaranteed to work across all handsets.. can you be more specific here?

Comment: @t0mm13b U8800 Huawei

Comment: Have searched on pdadb.net and gsmarena.com - zilch!

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question, but I this keyboard supports being paired with 3 devices at the same time, no tweaking required. I have it, and it's excellent. Not that expensive, either. https://www.amazon.com/Logitech-Bluetooth-Multi-Device-Smartphones-920-006342/dp/B00MUTWLW4/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1466584963&sr=8-1&keywords=bluetooth+logitech+keyboard