# Apple Keyboard and Magic Trackpad on Nexus S

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, bluetooth, samsung-nexus-s

I got inspired by the [Apple Keyboard and Magic Trackpad on Nexus 7 video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=68SONp6zTmU), but until I'll get my hands on a Nexus 7, I'm still proud of my good old Nexus S.

Now, I did turn on my Bluetooth, put both the Magic Trackpad and the Wireless Keyboard discoverable, scanned for new devices, but I cannot see them. If it makes any difference, I'm running Jelly Bean v4.1.2, so I'm hoping it's not the same story as in [the similar question regarding Android 2.3.5](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/30621/4168).

Is there a need for an extra application, or what's the way to get control over your Nexus S through your Apple bluetooth peripherals?