# How to connect 2 Bluetooth audio headsets to an Android phone?

Tags: bluetooth-audio, bluetooth-pairing

How can two people listen to audio on an Android phone over Bluetooth?  I.e. they have two Bluetooth headsets and want to pair both at the same time?

Answer (score 3):

As in most things, it depends. In this case, since you do not state your device, I will demonstrate from mine, a Samsung 8, running Android 9 (One UI). It explicitly allows dual Bluetooth through settings. If this is your device, click through to it at

`Settings > Connections > Bluetooth > Advanced > Dual Audio > ON`

The setting allows sound to two different Bluetooth devices.

If your device is different, look for the capability along a similar setting path.

Comment: It seems available on Samsung S** devices but not on A** devices: https://eu.community.samsung.com/t5/galaxy-a-series/galaxy-a8-2018-dual-audio/td-p/1009922
Is there another option?

Answer (score 1):

Most Android phones do not have the feature that allows more than one device to connect concurrently, but it's probably possible to send audio to two Bluetooth devices with extra hardware.

If your phone has an audio jack, that signal can be split into two using an adapter.  That would then have two wired headphones working. You could probably buy the wired splitter for $10 or so.

If your phone has an audio jack and would like to connect two Bluetooth devices, you can buy a *multi-point Bluetooth Transmitter*, also called *Bluetooth transmitter splitter sender*, which allows two devices to pair with it, and you connect the transmitter to the audio out jack of the phone. eBay has them for under $20.

If your phone doesn't have an audio jack,  There are many small, rechargeable Bluetooth receivers that can receive audio from your phone. They output on an audio jack, and you could proceed as above. If you need just audio, it would probably be fine, but if you want audio synced with a video you're watching, there would probably be a latency issue with receiving and retransmitting the signal.

It's possible that some company has produced or will produce a single device that offers two Bluetooth connection points for a reasonable price, and that might even address the latency problem.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from soldering 1 Bluetooth receiver output to two Bluetooth transmitter inputs, I cannot see a way to do it with the current Android Bluetooth setup. It only allows one device paired at a time. Could be an interesting hardware project if you are into that kind of thing.
Your phone connects to the Bluetooth receiver, while your two Bluetooth headsets each connects to one of the transmitters.

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12281/send-audio-to-two-a2dp-bluetooth-devices-simultaneously?rq=1              According to this, you either need a Samsung S8 or newer or Bluetooth 5...

Answer (score 0):

If budget is not a constraint, and you just want to connect multiple headsets in a fixed location, check out the Plantronics Savi 7xx or 8xxx line of headsets.  They are intended to allow monitoring of telemarketing calls, but we use it when my wife and I want to talk on the same mobile phone call.