# Why is there no option for Bluetooth Dual Audio in Android 11 and are there plans to add it?

Tags: bluetooth, audio, bluetooth-audio

It's strange that with most Android devices [you can only can output audio to one device connected to via Bluetooth at a time](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/218781/how-to-connect-2-bluetooth-audio-headsets-to-an-android-phone), especially since Dual Audio (output for two audio devices at once) is already possible with Samsung S8 and a few other Samsung devices.

Why hasn't this functionality been added to more or even all Android devices by now?

Are there any plans to add this feature (Dual Audio or audio output to more than 2 devices)? Is there ongoing development of this (maybe via a workaround)?

Comment: Dual Audio is a modification of Android by Samsung (may be even covered by patents - who knows?).

Comment: I don't think we can't answer this question since I've never ever heard of a leak on development plans (possibly due to NDA), unless the code is already committed to AOSP, or unless Google explained it publicly (but then XDA/Android news outlets would have noticed it before this community).

Comment: @AndrewT. We can assume that Android will earlier or later support the new Bluetooth audio standard (presented 2020 together with new new LC3 codec) which will by default support multiple audio streams  (e.g. multiple receiver or even split stream - one stream for left and the other for right ear). But that also requires new Bluetooth chips.

Comment: What's even more strange is I can't do this on my Samsung S21, but a S8 can?  Oh I think it either requires Bluetooth 5.0 or it only works with Galaxy Buds products.